# What is the probability that the area of triangle $PBC$ is less than half of the area of triangle $ABC$?

Tags: probability, geometry, discrete-mathematics

A point $P$ is randomly placed in the interior of the right triangle below. What is the probability that the area of triangle $PBC$ is less than half of the area of triangle $ABC$?

[image]

Can someone give me some hints on how to approach the problem?

One thing which I can see is that if we take $AB$ as the base of the triangle and drop a perp on $AB$ say at $D$. Then the area of CDA is half of the area of ABC. So the point P must be in the lower triangle CBD.

Comment: Drop perpendicular from $P$ to $CB$. Let's say the point of intersection is $Q$. If $PQ<0.5AC$ the area condition will be satisfied. So basically draw a midsegment parallel to $CB$ and find the ratio of trapezoid to area of $ABC$

Comment: https://web2.0calc.com/questions/halp-plz-on-these-questions-thx

Comment: @Etemon I saw the argument there but it was not clear to me.

Comment: Draw perp bisector of $AC$. Now any interior point $P$ below the perp bisector will give you $[PBC] \lt \frac 12 [ABC]$

Comment: Note since the base is shared by any triangle, the area of the generated triangle depends only on the height of P. Any two P candidates falling on the same horizontal line have triangles with the same area. The question becomes, at which height does the area become fifty fifty. From there it is the ratio of relevant areas.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Convince yourself $P$ must be within the trapezoid DEBC for the area condition to be met, and note triangles ADE and ACB are similar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If one shifts the point $P$ from left to right, i.e. parallel to $CB$, the area of the triangle $PBC$ does not change, because the base and the height remain the same.

So we are free to locate $P$ horizontally on the most convenient spot, which is on the interval $AC$. Comparison between the areas of $ABC$ and $PBC$ is now easy. We see that $P$ must be on the lower half of $AC$.

We conclude that all points $P$ below the horizontal line through the midpoint between $A$ and $C$ are valid. The area of this trapezoid is $3/4$ of the area of the triangle $ABC$. This is the probability that the OP asked for.